# How Can I Convert Nested YAML to nested Arrays and OpenStructs in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, nested, object-graph, openstruct

**How should I convert a series of nested hashes (nested to arbitrary depth) to a series of nested OpenStructs?** I'm loading in a big YAML file and I'm not enjoying `accessing['everything']['like']['this']`.

*I have found a few partial solutions using Google, but I thought this would make a nice question here.*

Here is one of the solutions I found from http://andreapavoni.com/blog/2013/4/create-recursive-openstruct-from-a-ruby-hash:

```
# deep_struct.rb
require 'ostruct'

class DeepStruct < OpenStruct
  def initialize(hash=nil)
    @table = {}
    @hash_table = {}

    if hash
      hash.each do |k,v|
        @table[k.to_sym] = (v.is_a?(Hash) ? self.class.new(v) : v)
        @hash_table[k.to_sym] = v

        new_ostruct_member(k)
      end
    end
  end

  def to_h
    @hash_table
  end

end
```

Problem with this solution is that it doesn't take arrays into account.

Comment: Don't the solutions work?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yep, they appear to be OK, but I'm interested to see other solutions people are using, and it's a question that hasn't been asked.

Comment: Why don't you post a couple of them and also tell why don't you like them?

Comment: Which behavior do you expect for arrays?

Comment: @tlewin Deserialised YAML is made of Arrays and Hashes, so I would want Arrays and OpenStructs.

Comment: give us the `YAML` sample, and also let us know what your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the solution (https://github.com/jsuchal/hashugar) i often use.

```
opts = Hashugar.new({:a => 1, 'b' => {:c => 2, :d => [3, 4, {:e => 5}]}})
```

But you also need to do:

`opts.b.d.last.e`

I do not understand how do you want to name array's getters. As Arup Rakshit sayed: give us yaml example and expected output or behavior.